# Is it haram if a girl touches herself?

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

I want to know that before marriage if a girl touches her sexual organ by herself, thinks about having sex and have the sensation, is it haram in Islam?
Please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Masturbation is haram, so yes touching with such intentions is haram too.

Comment: @BellaSwan No it is not, nor it is permitted. It still debated between scholars, so you might do it until the matter is resolved by the Ulama

Answer (score 1):

### In the name of God, the Beneficent, the Merciful

**All praise and thanks are due to God, the Lord of the worlds. We cannot find words to praise Him, as He only sees fit how laudation should be addressed to Him. We seek refuge in God from the evils within ourselves and the evils of our bad deeds. Whosoever God guides will never be led astray, and whosoever He leads astray will never find guidance. We bear witness that there is no god but God, the One without any associate, and We bear witness that Muhammad is His Messenger and bondman, peace and blessings be upon him, his kith and kin, his Companions and all those who follow their guidance until the Day of Judgment.**

---

**Your statement:** I want to know that before marriage if a girl touches her sexual organ by herself, thinks about having sex and have the sensation, is it haram in Islam? Please let me know.

**Answer:**

It is somewhat disliked for a man or woman to touch his or her own private parts (sexual organs) without need, since it entails going against religious propriety and modesty that Islam encourages for its followers.

> Sayyiduna Abdullah ibn Umar (God be pleased with him) narrates that the Messenger of God (God bless him & give him peace) passed by a man of Ansar who was admonishing his brother regarding modesty. The Messenger of God (God bless him & give him peace) said, **“Leave him, for modesty is part of Faith.”** (Sahih al-Bukhari & Sahih Muslim)

### 1. Sexual fantasies

You asked whether it is or not permissible for a girl to have sexual fantasies while touching her private parts? Well let's see, sexual fantasies are among the thoughts that cross a person’s mind because it is something that is stored in the subconscious which is affected by the environment in which he lives and the scenes that he sees. These are thoughts that occur to most people, especially the youth, but they vary from one person to another with regard to their type, strength and effect.

Islamic sharia is the sharia of the natural state of man and it is in harmony with human nature, and it takes into account the psychological fluctuation that God has made a part of the human make-up. So it does not go beyond human limitations or impose impossible burdens.

> It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may God be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of God be upon him) said: **“God has forgiven my people for whatever crosses their mind so long as they do not speak of it or act upon it.”** **Narrated by al-Bukhaari (2528) and Muslim (127).**

Some say that if you continue to think of sexual fantasies or dwell on it, then you are sinning by doing this but if it comes volunteer which means only sometimes but not with your intention, then you are forgiven if God wishes.

In my opinion, I think it is the best to refrain from such thoughts because slowly by slowly it will probably makes you obsessed and eventually you will commit adultery without your knowledge and this is very serious. Let's say, you are married, and you bring sexual stories to your spouse, do you think that your spouse will accept that? What would be his or her reaction? Have you thought about it? I think it is best not to dwell on such thoughts and do acts of worship which will benefit you in Hereafter such as praying regulate.

This is happening because it stems from a natural desire that human beings have and can best be resolved through marriage.

I have found a [**website**](http://ahmadjibril.com/qa/CPdesire.html) which have been discussed about this matter. You may look at the following list which is mentioned below.

So, according to my understanding, sexual fantasies must have also it's limits, I mean, you can't always think of this because I am sure that you have work to do and this might distract you from work. Because, everything must have limits because there is always something important to do such as studying, praying, fasting studying a chapter from Quran etc...

### 1. Masturbation

Masturbation is something shameful, and if you cannot handle yourself from that, then you find a spouse which is suitable for you. Because there is a narration:

> Abdullah bin Mas’ud Radiallahu anhu in Bukhari and Muslim. He says that Messenger (PUBH) said: **“O group of youth! Whoever from amongst you can marry should do so because it keeps the gaze low and it protects the private parts. And he who cannot marry should make it compulsory upon himself to fast because it breaks lust.”** (Bukhari : vol.6, pg.117 ; Muslim: vol.10, pg.172)

There is a verse from Quran I remember but not well that one can masturbate what only the right hand posses or from the spouse.

If you get married, then you may jack off, but as long as you are unmarried then you cannot do that unless you you do not take this as **habit** or you use haram **materials** such as pornography. That is why I think it is haram to jack off.

Now we are getting to final answer.

**CONCLUSION:** you should try your best to refrain from them because who knows, it could bring you a lot of harm and you will be blamed for your deeds so better to avoid than having sorrows later.

I hope this answers your question.

**We ask God to guide us to the Straight Path and to make us all people of Paradise. May God send blessings and peace upon His slave and Messenger Muhammad and upon his family and companions.**

---

**Sources:**

- [**Ruling on touching one's private parts**](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/6934)
- [**Ruling on sexual fantasies**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/84066/ruling-on-sexual-fantasies)
- [**The truth about masturbation**](https://archive.islamonline.net/?p=5424)
- [**Is masturbation healthy?**](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-the-counselor/addictions/is-masturbation-healthy/)

Answer (score -1):

In the name of Allah, the beneficent, the merciful.

In my thought, masturbation is a shameful thing if done in public. One should refrain from touching private parts while praying salat, or while making wudu (unless it is necessary in wudu) touching your private parts will break your wudu. Refrain from using toys, and do not use right hand, if you do masturbate, only use left hand.

ASSALAM-UALAIKUM.

Answer (score -2):

Masturbation is not Haraam because it's not made Haraam in the Quran and Allah would have used the word clearly.
I am not sure about imagination because it's not mentioned as well. I believe so, but not 100% correct (but I am sort of).

Comment: when you state something is haram or halal in islam, you have to provide definitive proof and evidence. assumptions made on personal opinion is not accepted. please provide the research effort for your answer.