# Is it haram to look at my own private part?

Tags: masturbation

I sometimes look at my private parts so I would like to know if it’s haram to look at my own private parts. And is it haram to masturbate cuz a lot of ppl said it’s haram and others said it’s not so I really don’t know who to believe

Comment: Those this answer your question  https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/53309/39820

Answer (score 0):

Masturbation is haram. If you want to stop then try to fast for it will be a shield for you and stay around your parents more so you dont look at evil videos.